# Is there a version of ereporter for Python 2.7

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm a big fan of the Google App Engine ereporter module. It sends you an email every day with all the errors you logged. I'm creating a new app, and it defaulted to Python 2.7 and multithreaded, and if I try to include ereporter I get errors because it relies on wsgi.

Is there any way to get this functionality with the non-deprecated python in GAE?

Answer (score 5):

This answer was offered on the gae mailing list, and it works!

```
handlers:
- url: /_ereporter.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.ereporter.report_generator.application
  login: admin
```